# N-Channel MOSFET as high-side switch

Tags: powermosfet

I propose using two N-channel enhancement mode MOSFETs to control 12V (VIN) and 5V power rails from a lower voltage (3V) MCU signal. I have connected the MCU control signal to a third MOSFET to toggle 12V as a common gate input. Are there any problems with this circuit?
[image]

Comment: Please draw your circuits conventionally: inputs on the left, outputs on the right. Your mirror-image circuit is harder to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there are many problems. Your load is permenently connected to VIN (or +5V) through body diode in your MOSFET. You need to use P-MOSFETs and adequate driver structure to control them by 3.3V signal. Or you can use integrated circuit called High side switch. Or use one of many other ways (photorelays etc, N-MOSFET with charge pump etc etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I should have explained that only one load will ever be connected and that it is just a relay coil. I don't think this will be affected by the diode.

Comment: @Mark If it’s a relay coil, why do you need a high side driver?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I see that my circuit is wrong and will go back to the drawing board!

Comment: @Mark - Hi, Since it seems that you want to finish with this question, please follow the process in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) article from the [help]. Consider accepting the "best" answer, in order to effectively show that you don't need further answers here, and your question has been answered. Thanks.